# make an object move directly towards a point and stop when it reaches it

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I make my object stop when it reaches the destination i gave it with my mouse click? The code makes the object move towards the point of a mouse click but I can't seem to find out how to make it stop, because it will almost never pass the specific destination point. :/ Somebody who knows how to accomplish this?

```
public function onMouseDown(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        if (this._character != null)
        {
            _character.isMoving = false;
            _character.dx = 0;
            _character.dy = 0;
            targetX = mouseX - _character.x;
            targetY = mouseY - _character.y;
            var angle:Number = Math.atan2(targetY,targetX);
            var dx:Number = Math.cos(angle) * _character.speed;
            var dy:Number = Math.sin(angle) * _character.speed;
            _character.dx = dx;
            _character.dy = dy;
            _character.isMoving = true;
        }

    }
    public function updateCharacter(e:Event):void
    {
        if (this._character.isMoving)
        {
            this._character.x +=  this._character.dx;
            this._character.y +=  this._character.dy;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Guest extends MovieClip
    {
        var walkSpeed:Number = 5;
        var oldPosX;
        var oldPosY;

        public function Guest()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, walk);
        }

        function walk(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            oldPosX = parent.mouseX;
            oldPosY = parent.mouseY;
            rotation = Math.atan2(oldPosY - y,oldPosX - x) / Math.PI * 180;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        }

        function loop(event:Event):void
        {
            // see if you're near the target
            var dx:Number = oldPosX - x;
            var dy:Number = oldPosY - y;
            var distance:Number = Math.sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy));
            if (distance<walkSpeed)
            {
                // if you are near the target, snap to it
                x = oldPosX;
                y = oldPosY;
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
            }
            else
            {
                x = x+Math.cos(rotation/180*Math.PI)*walkSpeed;
                y = y+Math.sin(rotation/180*Math.PI)*walkSpeed;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the conversion from radians to degrees and back again?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do it would be to calculate the angle to the point you want to stop at each time you move. This value should remain the same if you're moving in a straight line until you pass the point you're trying to stop at, at which point it will change drastically.

Once this happens, simply move your object back to the position it should have stopped at before you render it again.

---

I've created a demo with source code for you. There's a fair amount of code, so rather than posting everything here you can download the source instead:

http://martywallace.com/testing/gotoPoint.zip

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions have been asked many times.

However, see the code in my answer here that should explain how to move and stop.

[Movement of Objects in a simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247730/movement-of-objects-in-a-simulation/6255259#6255259)